# Magento Catalog URL Rewrites not indexing (site hosted in AWS EC2)

Tags: magento-1.9, core

I have two magento sites hosted in AWS. Two different sites and two different server. Only the Catalog URL Rewrites is not indexing. Is there something i have to configure in AWS?
magento v1.9.2.2

every time i have to `truncate core_url_rewrite` in phpmyadmin to index it. Please guide what i did wrong.

magento v1.9.2.2

Comment: what happen exactly if you try to reindex the url rewrites? I think your problem is not related to AWS

Comment: it doesnt index only the core_url_rewrite. everytime i have to  truncate via phpmyadmin. Only this table not indexing.  "Cannot initialize the indexer process." is the error message poping up